# Mobile app + Vapor/Perfect + Firebase/MongoDB?

Tags: android, ios, swift, mongodb, firebase

I´m going to start a mobile app project (both `Android` and `iOS` platforms) which will not have a huge amount of users at a first pilot phase, but which could increase in a second one. I need to think of the full end-to-end system infrastructure (Client-Server architecture), and I´m a bit unexperienced regarding server-side, so I´d really appreciate to get some guidence/recommendations.

My first approach is to set up a database system in a certain host (maybe should I consider a cloud solution?), so for that, if I´m not wrong, best options would be [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) and [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/). I need free solutions for the pilot phase, maybe I could consider paid ones for the second. I had a look at their websites, and I´m afraid I´m not clear of which option would be the most convenient and why:

A) Looks like `Firebase` is focused on mobile apps development, but I suppose front-end and back-end are then more coupled than with `MongoDB`. I tried to find any comparative with the pros and cons of both solutions with no success, is there somebody with experience on this who could help me?

B) I´m also considering a middle REST services layer with either [Perfect](http://perfect.org/) or [Vapor](https://vapor.codes/) to take advantage of my `Swift` knowledge. Similar issue to the one with the database system: which one would you recommend and why? It seems that both provide connectors to `MongoDB`, what about connecting them to `Firebase`?

C) Maybe should I consider a different middle layer and back-end infrastructure? As I said, I´m unexperienced about designing and building an end-to-end infrastructure as freelance. So I´d really appreciate to be able to get a clear overview for the whole infrastructure from someone experienced, or at least a starting point. Maybe could somebody recommend a good article/blog/tutorial about this topic?

Thanks

Comment: I am here just to give some pointers regarding Firebase. The platform seems like a perfect fit for the pilot phase - it offers everything you need and since you won't have a lot users it is still free. You can also have everything running in no time thanks to simple documentation.
 We are running few full projects (all of them iOS + Android + web) everything using Firebase. The web app is hosted there, mobile platforms are using SDKs which also provide analytics + crash reports and many other stuff.
I think you should check it out, see few examples or maybe try it out to see if it fits you

Comment: @ZassX Thanks for the tip, I'll check Firebase. However, I'd need to take into account also scalability, in case of a noticeable increase of users and services in a latter phase, so the effort to move from Firebase to a different infrastructure

Comment: Of course, go through and really make sure it is right choice for you. Firebase uses noSQL so I think there should be no problem with moving to new infrastructure, at lease for database. You have an option to export everything. However, you would have to figure something out for users since there is no option for that.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow